# Slackware: elilo doesn't boot unless I insert the installation media

Tags: boot-loader, slackware, lilo

I've just installed slackware on a new SSD on dual boot with windows.
I installed it using a botable flash drive. Without it Elilo keeps stuck on the loading screen prompting:

```
Loading kernel vmlinuz ... done
```

In the folder `/boot/efi/EFI/Slackware/` I have only `elilo.conf`, `elilo.efi` and `vmlinuz`.

My `/boot/efi/EFI/Slackware/elilo.conf`:

```
chooser=simple
timeout=1

image=vmlinuz
     label=vmlinuz
     read-only
     append="root=/dev/sda5 vga=normal ro"
```

What happened to its `initrd.gz` and why am I using this image instead of the standard huge kernel when first install it?

How can I safely fix it?

Had to reinstall it because I enabled the generic kernel and edited `elilo.conf` and all `efi/` content was lost out of nothing. Just like that.

**Why does it need the installation media to boot like this?**

This the first time it happens to me and never had any problems using slackware until now.